# Perimeter and area of a rectangle is given.How to find the ratio between two sides of rectangle?

Tags: geometry, quadratics

If the perimeter of a rectangle is $160$ meters and its area is $1200$ square meter, then one of its sides must be __________ the other side.

My approach to this question is:

$$x=\text{one  side}$$

$$y=\text{other side}$$

$$x+y+x+y=160$$

$$x\times{y}=1200$$

$$2(x+y)=160$$

$$x=80-y$$

$$x\times{y}=1200$$

$$(80-y)\times{y}=1200$$

$$y^2+80y-1200=0$$

Am i going in right direction? If yes, then I stuck at this point.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

Sumaira

Comment: This is good so far (just check the signs in the last line) --- use the quadratic formula next!

Comment: Actually, there is/are sign problems in $y^2 + 80 y-1200=0$.  Note that $(80 - y) \cdot y = 80y - y^2$.

Comment: Thankyou, after applying quadratic formula I got two values of y that are, 60 and 20. And when I substitute these two values in equation x * y = 1200 I got two values of X 20 and 60. It means answer is one- third?

Comment: @BillWallis  Kindly confirm my answer.

Comment: @SumairaRounaq That sounds good to me.

Comment: Any of  "one-third of, or three times" the other side, or "one-third of" or "three times" is true and is therefore a correct answer.